How to Migrate the Docker Compose Manifest to Kubernetes?
Context
I have worked extensively with celery workers and docker, but my knowledge of Kubernetes is very basic. Here is the architecture diagram of how I am serving some machine learning models in production via multiple celery task servers. (I hope the figure conveys the essentials, but ask me if anything unclear.)

Basically, the user (not necessarily a human user, but a frontend client) sends request to a FastAPI server (running via uvicorn). One redis service acts as the message broker between the ASGI (FastAPI) and the celery workers. Once a task is received, the end user gets a task id which he uses to poll the status and get the result. The bidirectional arrows represent duplex data flow to send the task parameters, the task id, receive status, results etc.
For sake of completeness, here is the Docker-compose I am using to fire up all the services, and expose the FastAPI.
version: '2'
services:
  redis: # Private redis service
    image: "redis:alpine"

  worker: # Private workers
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./docker/worker/Dockerfile
    image: worker_image
    # container_name: worker_container
    depends_on:
      - redis
    deploy:
      replicas: 3 # Replicas require unique container names 

  asgi: # Only container that is exposed to the user
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./docker/asgi/Dockerfile
    image: asgi_image
    container_name: asgi_container
    ports:
      - "8080:8080" # host:container
    depends_on:
      - worker

It is working fine.
Goal
But docker-compose does not offer container orchestration across different nodes, so I want to shift the deployment to a kubernetes taking advantage of horizontal scaling. I was hoping since the components are already containerised, it should not be difficult. But I am not sure how how to manage what appears to be three layers of the architecture, where only the worker layer needs replication. So I need some hints on how to write the deployment, service and ingress manifests.
I am using a managed CIVO cluster (if that's relevant), so basic provisioning is not an issue. As for the orchestration, my first thought is

Write the Celery containers inside a deployment manifest with necessary number of replicas
Run the ASGI and Redis (which do not need replicas) outside Kubernetes as standalone (unmanaged) containers
Expose only the ASGI to the outside world, as before

But is there a better way, to put everything inside a cluster? How should the deployment and service manifests look like?
You do not have to write out the complete manifest files for me, but some hints from experienced DevOps gurus will be sincerely appreciated.

You'll probably find it easier to run everything inside the cluster than to have a mix of Kubernetes and non-Kubernetes components.  Otherwise this architecture doesn't seem too complicated; what have you tried already and what problems are you running into?

Thanks. My thought is to use redis as a single replica deployment and clusterip service, the asgi as a single replica deployment and loadbalancer service (as it's exposed to the outside world) and the workers running only the deployment with 3 replicas (without service). Does it sound sensible?

You can try using https://kompose.io/ to convert your docker-compose to Kubernetes manifest files.
You might need to configure ingress for asgi_container https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/

Thanks a lot, is there a simple web interface for the kube-kompose where I can, sort of, paste/upload the docker-compose.yaml and see the outcome?

I am not aware of any web interface, but kompose installation is straightforward https://kompose.io/installation/#installation
